# PHP Can't find the variable to show products on my include page, Any suggestions?

Tags: php, mysql, web, isset

I'm trying to create a php include file for my ecommerce website which will be in the centre of the page that will display the products. The database is connected. I have this but it keeps saying "Data to render this page is missing". The variable is not being set. I'm a relative beginner and I dont know what to do.

Thanks in advance!

```
// Check to see the URL variable is set and that it exists in the database
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    // Connect to the MySQL database  
    include "config.inc.php"; 
    $id = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $_GET['id']); 
    // Use this var to check to see if this ID exists, if yes then get the product 
    // details, if no then exit this script and give message why
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1");
    $productCount = mysql_num_rows($sql); // count the output amount
    if ($productCount > 0) {
        // get all the product details
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
            $product_name = $row["product_name"];
            $price = $row["price"];
            $details = $row["details"];
            $category = $row["category"];
            $subcategory = $row["subcategory"];
            $date_added = strftime("%b %d, %Y", strtotime($row["date_added"]));
        }
    } else {
        echo "That item does not exist.";
        exit();
    }
} else {
    echo "Data to render this page is missing.";
    exit();
}
```

Comment: @hakre How do i set it then? Thanks for the quick reply

Comment: Did you put `id=something` into the query string for whatever this page's address is?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing an 'id' in the url. The url you are calling should look like this

```
www.example.com/product.php?id=1
```

You were getting an error because the script is telling you that there is no 'id' value.

Comment: `www.example.com/product.php?id=1`

Comment: Yes i tried to bold the id=1 and it added those funny asterisks :)

Comment: Basically I have a template a header, footer, left nav and right block. This is the middle include which will go inside the template. I want to pull the products out of my database when i click on the left navigation -'products'. SO there shouldn't be an ID right?

Comment: When you click on the URL in your left nav make sure you add the id of you product to the end of the url www.example.com/product.php?id=1, www.example.com/product.php?id=2 etc. Middle include file will see the value. All include files in the page see the values which are passed in the URL.

Comment: I'm trying to pull all the products though. The example page I got this from works perfectly fine.

Comment: isa.cems.uwe.ac.uk/~j39-green/ISD4/index.php?p=product its local so you can't viiew it.

Comment: Your url should look like this in order for this to work isa.cems.uwe.ac.uk/~j39-green/ISD4/index.php?p=product&id=1 (1 is an example so id should be which ever product if u are trying to pull out)

Comment: how would i pick out all of them? I'm so confused, my deadlines tomorrow aswell.

Comment: Well it is very hard to determine but the ids should be available to you.